# dfs/cifs problems with kernel 4.18 (rhel8)

Tags: cifs, dfs, rhel8

We have a rhel8   environment with several windows fileservers in dfs using cifs (auto)mounts.
The mount is working when accessed, but  when  the cifs filesytems/mounts  are   in heavy use the cifs mount will hang the server intermitted. Only a reboot the linux server will release it.  In the console and dmesg the server is waiting for a windows (namespace) fileserver.
There is a  DFS namespace  with two namespace servers
Rhel8 support now dfs failover it seems,  we didn't have this problems with Rhel7.
It looks like it switches between namespace servers, proberly caused by load on the microsoft fileserver.

I've no access to the microsoft environment, or i've no knowledge of ms...
My questions is, did anyone experience the same problems?
Is it allowed to use 2 namespace servers?
(yes, i've made a ticket at Redhat about this issue)

Example autofs configuration, //examplenet.com/dfsroot/subdfsroot is the dfs root:

/etc/auto.master

/mnt/share1/mount/submount /etc/auto.cifs --timeout=60

/etc/auto.cifs

2021 -fstype=cifs,dom=domain,uid=1001,gid=1003,noserverino,vers=3.0,username=yyyyy,password=xxxxx ://examplenet.com/dfsroot/subdfsroot/2021
2022 -fstype=cifs,dom=domain,uid=1001,gid=1003,noserverino,vers=3.0,username=yyyyy,password=xxxxx ://examplenet.com/dfsroot/subdfsroot/2022
2023 -fstype=cifs,dom=domain,uid=1001,gid=1003,noserverino,vers=3.0,username=yyyyy,password=xxxxx ://examplenet.com/dfsroot/subdfsroot/2023

active mounts when accessed:

//examplenet.com/dfsroot/subdfsroot/2021  750G  712G   39G  95% /mnt/share1/mount/submount/2021
//examplenet.com/dfsroot/subdfsroot/2022  750G  712G   39G  95% /mnt/share1/mount/submount/2022
//examplenet.com/dfsroot/subdfsroot/2023   81G   11G   71G  14% /mnt/share1/mount/submount/2023